# Invalid postback or callback argument when trying to do fire a Jquery function from Server side

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to fire a Jquery function form my C#.NET server side code. basically what im trying is to show a notification. Im using Bootstrap and I have loaded my scripts in the master page. Also I have added my **Form** and **ScriptManager** tags in master page. I have a function written in my inner Page Document.Ready. now im trying to call that function from my server side code.

Server Side Code-

```
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "showAlertMessages", "showSuccessMessage('Your Password Changed Successfully.');", true);
```

Client Side function -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    function showSuccessMessage(message) {
        alert(message);
    }
});
</script>
```

But when I do this, It gives me the

```
Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.
```

I have tried turning off the event validation, then the error does not come but the function is not getting called.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Remove the `$(document).ready(function () {});` wrapper. You're trying to call a global function, but that wrapper makes it not global. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/215552

Comment: tried this also. Again the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `String.Format` like this:

```
const string message = "Your Password Changed Successfully.";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "showAlertMessages", String.Format("showSuccessMessage('{0}');", message), true);
```

Comment: have you turned off your event validation and then tried this? @KasunKoswattha